# Image of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of complex function $f(z)=z^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

We want to map a line that does not go trough origo via mapping $z\mapsto z^{-1}$.

I have a result that a line $ax+by+c=0$ can be represented in a form $\overline{w}z+w\overline{z}+\delta=0$, where $w\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have to show that the image of the mapping of the line is a circle.

Can I express the set of circle as $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \ \  \mid z \mid=r ,0<r\in\mathbb{R} \}$?

I am new to complex functions, please give hints.

Comment: No, the center of the circle can can be different from zero, so it must be of the form
$$|z-z_0|=r$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- As the function is radially symmetric, prove the result only for a vertical line
- For vertical lines (not through the origin),i.e. given by $\Re(z)=x_0\neq 0$, it is easy to find the center of the circle the line is mapped to (just see that the point on the real axis and the point at infinity are mapped to points on a diameter, and their images are easy to calculate, the center will be the midpoint of the diameter.)
- now that you have the center, say $z_0$, prove that
  $$\left|\frac{1}{x_0+iy}-z_0\right|$$
  is constant.

Solutions: I give you the solution in the case $z\mapsto \frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ (because I had it already written down), but the calculation is very similar. In my case the center was located at $\frac1{2x_0}$. And thus we computed
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{\overline{x_0+it}}-\frac{1}{2x_0}\right|& =\left|\frac{x_0+it}{\overline{x_0+it}(x_0+it)}-\frac{1}{2x_0}\right|\\
& = \left|\frac{2x_0(x_0+it)-(\overline{x_0+it})(x_0+it)}{2x_0|x_0+it|^2}\right|\\
& = \left|\frac{x_0^2+2x_0it-t^2}{2x_0|x_0+it|^2}\right|\\
& = \frac{|(x_0+it)^2|}{2|x_0||x_0+it|^2}\\
& = \left|\frac{1}{2x_0}\right|,
\end{align*}
which is constant.

Comment: I still keep getting into expressions that I cannot simplify onwards. Is the actual calculation process simple? Because I think I keep taking a wrong turn in some point.

Comment: @Arcturus See my edit. In my case the function was $$ \frac{1}{\color{red}{\bar{z}}},$$but besides that, the calculations are almost the same

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I just wonder what my original hint ($\overline{w}z+w\overline{z}+\delta $) is for..? Because I tried to plug in $z=\dfrac{-w\overline{z}-\delta}{\overline{w}}$ and tried to calculate the $z^{-1}$ from that...

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how to implement your given hint, at this vey moment